# How should method names change when I turn a mutable object into an immutable object?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, immutability

Lets say I have a class Size.

With the mutable version it feels natural to go

```
size.add(2);
```

But the immutable feels better like this

```
newSize = size.plus(2);
```

I'm fairly new to immutable objects. What is the naming convention for this and other methods?

Comment: The problem is that `add` is also used for immutable objects.  I suggest having a convention which applies to all methods like `copyAndAdd(2)` or `addToSelf(2)` if you want to make it clear. Another option is to avoid mixing them in the same classes. Just make it one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is asking for opinions, not for facts.

You can let yourself be guided by the BigDecimal class for the naming convention:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

But if you want to use "plus" in stead of "add" - why not? Its your code and if you find that readable then just do it.

EDIT: please be aware that I did not notice your stackoverflow history before giving this answer. I would have probably chosen to shut up if I had noticed you are not a novice :)